# Phrase experimentation - Marching a trough

Tags: word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests

I'm trying to touch up this part, and wondering if the above could work as a metaphor.

This is my text right now:

> “George, it's me, .... I can't connect with my money!” he fired while marching back and forth in his living room...

I don't like using *back and forth* right here, and wondering if it could work with -

> ... he fired while marching a trough up and down his living room (floor?)

I could use *up and down* anyway, but came up with this visual to go with the firing and wondering if it's too much, or if it sounds fine.

Could also be *pacing up and down*, and leave it alone...

TIA

Comment: As he wore a path in the rug pacing back and forth.

Comment: pacing anxiously ... wearing a path, as Hot Licks suggests

Comment: Someone has to be the first to use a new metaphor. I find this quite creative and expressive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one would march a **trough** *into* the floor or *across* a room. While *down* and **trough** have some natural affinity, *up* and **trough** do not.